# Returned type of a function is not inferred when it's declared as generic from the function's argument

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

### The problem

I have the following two types.

```js
interface SchemaItem {
  name: string,
  value: string
}

type Result<T extends SchemaItem[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K['name']]: K['value']
}
```

And I have a function that is supposed to create a value of the `Result` type from the `SchemaItem[]` argument.

```js
function createResult<T extends SchemaItem[]>(schemaItems: T): Result<T> {
  // implementation doesn't matter for this question
  return {} as Result<T>
}
```

The `Result` type works as expected when I test it like this.

```js
// ResultType = { foo: "Foo", bar: "Bar" }
type ResultType = Result<[
  { name: 'foo', value: "Foo" },
  { name: 'bar', value: "Bar" },
]>
```

But when I test the function with the same data the returned value is not inferred properly.

```js
// result is of type Result<{ name: string; value: string }[]>
const result = createResult([
  { name: 'foo', value: "Foo" },
  { name: 'bar', value: "Bar" },
])
```

Is it possible to make TypeScript infer the type of the `result` as `{ foo: "Foo", bar: "Bar" }` or it's a design limitation?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwJKTbIDeAUMsiHNhAFzIDOYUoA5gDTnIBucANgFc6jZm1IBfUqTABPAA4oAShAYC+YADwAVZBAAekEABMGaTDnyEA2gF0AfMgC8JLlYDSyUMi1WQA7ABG0DbIcKZuVgDkVDSRNjb0EZG8ghBxElKyCsjKqupa8ijOuWqaVlzElNTCkTAA9nWR7Dz8QvQARABiDe3I4pwUlTE1AXBQTS2pHQBCY739pPZSMAIgCGDAdSDICFAQcJAl6tq6BhDGpuhYuAQ4tnYAFAzmN4QM9FoAlPRHmloOZAoezAAig22I4lCpl+2jsGVICC2TGQezyYCcOz2Bwgvwe5UGVRo9FqDQmKTayC6PT6AxIhJGYzJrWE7VmUHmnBsnyAA)

### What I have tried

I thought maybe the problem is that `name` property of `SchemaItem` is declared as `string` and here is what I come up with.

```js
interface SchemaItem<T extends string = string> {
  name: T,
  value: string
}

type ArrayToUnion<T> = T extends Array<infer R> ? R : never

type Result<T extends SchemaItem[]> = ArrayToUnion<T> extends SchemaItem<infer R> ? { [key in R]: string } : never
```

But it didn't help and the `result` value was of type `{ [x: string]: string }` which is no better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your generics from `readonly` array types, and then supply a readonly array of object literal types to the function by using the [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the input. (Using an `as const` assertion tells the compiler to infer the type literally.)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwJKTbIDeAsAFDLIhzYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0FVAbnABsArg2asOFAL4UKYAJ4AHFACUITIQLAAeACrIIAD0ggAJk2RQIcEwHsQAuWkw58hANoBdAHzIAvCR5kNwBpZFBkHTcQIWwAI2gPZDhzYLcAcho6NI8PRlS0-mEIbKkZcnklZFV1TR1FFH9qjW03QOJqWlE0mBsbNM5kQpFGACIAMV6R5EluShIOukY02LgofsHBYeQRgCFVqZmKbzKYIRAEMGA7ZARLOEgmzV19IwhTczvbe0d0LFwCHCeLwACiYzn+hCYjB0AEpGI9tDofGQ5pYwEIoCASJIkuYEbovKVyBQEHYWBY1M0-Dc7g9KZpga05u1Ml0en0BkNRONJtNZlQWZ0lis1pzNty9lADrNEskbmSwDCANxlSw1MAAOhFSuQAHpddtJSMKGrmhr2Tr9dsJjYRkA)

```ts
interface SchemaItem {
  name: string,
  value: string
}

type Result<T extends readonly SchemaItem[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K['name']]: K['value']
}

type ResultType = Result<[
  { name: 'foo', value: "Foo" },
  { name: 'bar', value: "Bar" },
]>

function createResult<T extends readonly SchemaItem[]>(schemaItems: T): Result<T> {
  return {} as Result<T>
}

const result = createResult([
  { name: 'foo', value: "Foo" },
  { name: 'bar', value: "Bar" },
] as const);

result.bar; // "Bar"
result.foo; // "Foo"
```